# v-data-table in component: how to have all items selected by default?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a `v-data-table` in a component, and am using the checkboxes created by `select-all` to filter information in the component's parent. None of the rows start off selected. I would like all of them to be checked by default.

Things that have not worked:

- in the parent's `data`: setting `selectedItems` to `Array.from(this.$store.state.tableItems)` by default (the item in the store isn't defined at that point)
- in the `mounted` or `created` event in the child: setting `selectedItems` to `Array.from(this.tableItems)` (this produces an "avoid mutating a prop directly" error)

I feel like there is probably a way to do this with a computed property?

(There is probably also a more idiomatic way using actions or events or something? I am new to Vue.)

**MyComponent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :value="selectedItems"
    @input="$emit('update:selectedItems', $event)"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="tableItems"
    item-key="id"
    select-all
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>
        <v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" hide-details></v-checkbox>
      </td>
      <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    tableItems: { type: Array, },
    selectedItems: { type: Array, },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'ID', value: 'id', },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

```html
<template>
  <MyComponent :tableItems="tableItems" :selectedItems.sync="selectedItems"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItems: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tableItems() {
      return this.$store.state.tableItems;  // set by an axios request in beforeCreate in App.vue
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, the following did work (I was already using Vuex) but I'm hoping someone else has a more satisfying answer.

**store.js**

Track the selected items here. The default value of null is so that, when setting the table items after the first axios call finishes, we can set the default.

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    tableItems: {},
    selectedItems: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    setTableItems(state, payload) {
      state.tableItems= payload;
      if (state.selectedItems == null) state.selectedItems = payload;
    },
    setSelectedItems(state, payload) {
      state.selectedItems = payload;
    },
  }
});
```

**MyComponent.vue**

What changed here is that I'm using the selected elements to the Vuex store as the value for the data table, and then committing a mutation on every input.

```html
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :value="selectedItems"
    @input="updateSelectedItems"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="tableItems"
    item-key="id"
    select-all
  >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
      <td>
        <v-checkbox v-model="props.selected" hide-details></v-checkbox>
      </td>
      <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    tableItems: { type: Array, },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: 'ID', value: 'id', },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateSelectedItems(event) {
      this.$store.commit("setSelectedItems", event);
    },
  },
  computed: {
    selectedItems() { return this.$store.state.selectedItems; },
  }
};
</script>
```

**Parent.vue**

This ends up being a lot simpler; less data binding, just referencing the store.

```html
<template>
  <MyComponent :tableItems="tableItems"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  computed: {
    tableItems() { return this.$store.state.tableItems; },
    selectedItems() { return this.$store.state.selectedItems; },
  }
};
</script>
```